# filter blur is overflowing CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

filter blur is overflowing to header and sidebar. It is looking ugly ("overflow: hidden" doesn't work)

How to I fix the overflow ?

HTML:

```
<div class="subscribe">
  <div class="subscribe__content">
    <div class="subscribe__left">
      <h2>Subscribe</h2>
      <input type="text" class="subscribe__field" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="button" class="subscribe__btn" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <div class="subscribe__right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.subscribe{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;

  &::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://i.hurimg.com/i/hdn/75/0x0/5de62c4a0f25441e58232693.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(25px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've restructured your styles to set `background-image` to the element, and use a `backdrop-filter` on your `::before` element. That way the corners will always be sharp but the `blur` filter will still be applied on the background.

Also, make sure that your `.subscribe__content` has `z-index` greater than `.subscribe::before`.

```
.subscribe {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background: url('https://i.hurimg.com/i/hdn/75/0x0/5de62c4a0f25441e58232693.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;

  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
    z-index: 10;
  }

  &__content {
    z-index: 20;
  }
}
```